# Using doParallel instead of apply

Tags: r, parallel-processing, apply

I am trying to use `doParallel` to apply a `function` to each row of a `data.frame` instead of using `apply`.  I posted a question about this earlier here:

[doParallel instead of apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69258578/doparallel-instead-of-apply)

The answer posted to my earlier question worked for the example I provided at that time but does not work with the example below.  In my current example I create a trivial `function` that for each row of one `data.frame` simply renames `columns` of a second `data.frame`.  If I do not rename the `columns` of the second `data.frame` in the `function` then the answer posted to my earlier question works.

Here is the first `data.frame`:

```
df1 <- read.table(text = '
    aa bb cc dd  ee
     1  7  8  9  10
     2 70 80 90 100
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Here is the second `data.frame`:

```
df2 <- read.table(text = '
   SS TT YY UU II
    4  5  6 CH  7
   44 55 66 CH 77
', header = TRUE)
```

Here is my function:

```
my.function1 <- function(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) {
  colnames(df2) <- c('qqq', 'www', 'eee', 'rrr', 'ttt')
  return = list(new.df=df2)
}
```

The `apply` statement works:

```
function.output <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) {my.function1(x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5])})
function.output
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$new.df
#  qqq www eee rrr ttt
#1   4   5   6  CH   7
#2  44  55  66  CH  77
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$new.df
#  qqq www eee rrr ttt
#1   4   5   6  CH   7
#2  44  55  66  CH  77
```

The `doParallel` statement does not work:

```
library(doParallel)
dat1 <- df1
ncores1 <- detectCores()-5
c1 <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores1)
registerDoParallel(c1)

v1 <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(dat1)) %dopar% {
     my.function1(dat1[i,1], dat1[i,2], dat1[i,3], dat1[i,4], dat1[i,5])
}
#Error in { : task 1 failed - "object 'df2' not found"
v1
stopCluster(c1)
#Error: object 'v1' not found
```

If I modify the `function` so it does not rename the `columns` of the second `data.frame` then the `doParallel` statement does work:

```
my.function2 <- function(aa, bb, cc, dd, ee) {
  return = list(new.df=df2)
}

dat2 <- df1
ncores2 <- detectCores()-5
c2 <- parallel::makeCluster(ncores2)
registerDoParallel(c2)

v2 <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(dat2)) %dopar% {
     my.function2(dat2[i,1], dat2[i,2], dat2[i,3], dat2[i,4], dat2[i,5])
}
v2
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$new.df
#  SS TT YY UU II
#1  4  5  6 CH  7
#2 44 55 66 CH 77
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$new.df
#  SS TT YY UU II
#1  4  5  6 CH  7
#2 44 55 66 CH 77
stopCluster(c2)
```

How can I get the `doParallel` statement to work while renaming the `columns` of the second `data.frame` in the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.export`

```
v1 <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(dat1), .export = "df2") %dopar% {
     my.function1(dat1[i,1], dat1[i,2], dat1[i,3], dat1[i,4], dat1[i,5])
}
```

-output

```
> v1
[[1]]
[[1]]$new.df
  qqq www eee rrr ttt
1   4   5   6  CH   7
2  44  55  66  CH  77


[[2]]
[[2]]$new.df
  qqq www eee rrr ttt
1   4   5   6  CH   7
2  44  55  66  CH  77
```

Comment: If I have three data.frames and want to rename the columns of two of them in the function can I use something like `.export = c("df2", "df3")` or `.export = list("df2", "df3")`?

Comment: @MarkMiller it should be `c("df2", "df3")`